# in inAPP server model purchase which content is given to device by server at last for subscription?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, ios-4.2

I am working with inAPP purchase server model.I have confusion about last step in servermodel after finished receipt verification.Which contents are given by server to device and how it manage subscriptions?i know all receipts data are store into server but how this service is giving to device and how device get notify about its subscription's expire date? please any one have idea then please share..thank you

Comment: please mention, why do you want to know the expiration date?application itself will notify you about it(if it has one). because as per apple's documentation the receipt has no key for this.

Comment: Yeah friend its true but I want to know that at last step in server model they describe "contents are deliver to device"..I want to ask which contents are deliver apart from receipt details?thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

As you have already gone through this

**Server Product Model**

In the server product model, you provide a separate server that delivers products to your iOS application. Server delivery is appropriate for subscriptions, services and content, because these products can be delivered as data without altering your application bundle. For example, a game might deliver new play environments (puzzles or levels) to the application.

If note this point

**Server delivery is appropriate for subscriptions, services and content, because these products can be delivered as data without altering your application bundle**

```
and example
```

A game might deliver new play environments (puzzles or levels) to the application.
[Generally this kind of model is used when you have thin mobile client which relies on server for its data(or it can have initial set of data, It can have rich graphics]